# ls -e option not available in linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, ls

I have shell scripts that run on Solaris UNIX that use the `-e` option on `ls` to ensure the same format for all files regardless of their age.  This option is not available on Linux.  The exact same format is important.  Is there a similar option I can use for Linux?  Or better yet, is there a way to update ls to use the `-e` option?  That way I won't have to create exception code for Linux.

---

[OpenSolaris manpage for ls](http://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1/ls/):

> ***-e*** The same as ***-l***, except displays time to the second, and with one format for all files regardless of age: `mmm dd hh:mm:ss yyyy`.

Comment: For those who don't have a Solaris box to hand, could you [edit] your question to give an example where `-e` is significant?

Comment: have you checked the documented (man ls) --full-time ?

Comment: Why would you use `ls` in the first place? A better approach would be to tell us what you are using it for and we can provide you with portable tools that won't suffer from these issues. Parsing `ls` is [almost never the right solution.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: I'm sure there are better ways to do what I'm doing but the scripts that use the -e option already exist. The questions was, is there a way to recreate the output of the -e option on linux for the ls command so the scripts used on Solaris do not have to be too much different than the scripts on Linux to minimize exception coding. If the answer is no, then the scripts will have to updated and tested and this is just a different between Linux and Unix I'll have to live with.

Comment: Note that that has nothing to do with Linux. Linux is only a kernel. Systems with a Linux kernel often also have GNU utilities which may be the one you're refering to. Some other Linux based systems have busybox ls instead, some have no ls at all. It would be better to specify the OS instead (Debian/RedHat/ChromeOS/Android/OpenWrt..) or the implementation of `ls` (like GNU, busybox, heirloom (a port of OpenSolaris tools))

Comment: @zajlzoo 1) if you're David, please [merge your accounts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). 2) If you are going to have to edit the scripts anyway, why not do the job properly and use portable tools instead? Any solution we come up with will involve editing your scripts, why not fix them for good?

Answer (score 3):

Using `--time-style=+FORMAT` you can set the formatted output like `ls -l --time-style=+"%b %_d %H:%M:%S %Y"`

Perhaps you can set an `alias` on the Linux hosts to default the `--time-style` on every `ls` invocation.

Comment: Or maybe just a `alias le='ls -l --time-style=+"%b %_d %H:%M:%S %Y"'`.

Comment: `%_d` isn't portable; `%e` is a more portable way (of course, it'd only be relevant on this case on platforms with gnu ls but not glibc). The actual time format used by solaris is `%b %e %T %Y`.

Comment: According to the manual page on my host `%_d` is equivalent to `%e`. Look also at the `Glibc notes` section of `man strftime` or search for `padding`.

Answer (score 0):

The "modern" flag for not simplifying time is `-T`. I.e., `ls -lT` will show time to the minute even for very old files. Note that `-T` does not imply `-l`, so Solaris `-e` is equivalent to `-lT`. See if your system supports it.